# Setting up a load balancer using nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am learning how to set up a load balancer, using nginx on AWS.

I set up a basic ubuntu 18.04 server on AWS, and then did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install nginx -y
```

I then replaced /etc/nginx/nginx.conf with the following:

```
upstream backend {
    server xxx.24.20.11;
    server xxx.24.20.12;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

I then tried restarting the nginx server by doing:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

but I'm getting the error message:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I did

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

And here's what I got:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-04-03 01:13:27 UTC; 23s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1822 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1748 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1865 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 1752 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxxx.com systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxx.com nginx[1865]: nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxx.com nginx[1865]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxx.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxx.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 01:13:27 load-balancer.xxx.com systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

## I looked at two separate tutorials, and they both use the "upstream" directive. Any ideas?

## Edit:

I returned nginx.conf to its original format:

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/nginx.original /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then, I did the following:

```
sudo su
echo > /etc/nginx/sites-available/load-balancer.conf
```

I then added the following to /etc/nginx/sites-available/load-balancer.conf

```
http {
  upstream backend {
    server docker-one.xxxxxxx.com;
    server docker-two.xxxxxxx.com;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
  }
}
```

load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com is the domain name that I am using for testing, and the docker-one and docker-two are the two domains that will be running the actual web app.

I then did a symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/load-balancer.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

then I rebooted the server. When it was back up, I did the following:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

I got an error message telling me the nginx service failed, so I did:

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-04-03 19:42:34 UTC; 19s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1549 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 03 19:42:34 load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 03 19:42:34 load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com nginx[1549]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Apr 03 19:42:34 load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 03 19:42:34 load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 19:42:34 load-balancer.xxxxxxx.com systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting whole nginx.conf you deleted http context. upstream is only allowed inside http {} block as per https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

Debian/ubuntu uses /etc/nginx/sites-available/* for site definitions, thats where you need to create your own config file, one per vhost if needed. And then enable it so it becomes symlinked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*. Or for simplicity, use /etc/nginx/sites-available/default as existing config file, make your changes there. Save original, until you get it working. And reload nginx after said changes. Restore original /etc/nginx/nginx.conf also, ofcourse.

Comment: I tried it with http context and it did not work either. This is not related to nginx not being able to find the configuration file

Comment: As your error message and your description said, you removed whole default nginx.conf, overwriting it with block of config that should reside inside rest of config.

What is error message in logs this time? As in not just "did not work".

As one said, restore original state of nginx and modify file default inside sites-available directory. You may want to confirm after nginx clean install also, that it works as-is.

Comment: As far as I know, nginx default install works out of the box just fine. In case it reports anything like nginx.conf failing test, you had to change something in it, its not original one. So, in case you botch its config and cant revert it manually, its best to remove and purge said application and install it cleanly, to get to the state where it initially works. Then proceed editing correct config files...

Comment: Yes, default install works. My question is about setting nginx up as a load balancer, and I was following a tutorial on how to do that

Comment: Yes, failed to read and understand your posts couple of times, it goes bit over my head. Perhaps someone else can help out.